# Place the cut field in the desired position of ouput file

Tags: text-processing

I am writing a script like in which, it will `cut` the fields from input file and append to output file.

```
cat $1|while read line
do
acc_no=`echo "$line" | cut -c29-43`
acc_type=`echo "$line"|cut -c124-125`
echo "$acc_no","$acc_type" >> out.csv
done
```

here it is separated by ','. Now I want in output file like

`acc_no` from positions `20 to 33` in output file
`acc_type` from positions `1 to 2` in output file

I do not need any delimiters, I want to access these things by the positions.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand. What is your input file's format? What exactly do you want the output to look like?

Comment: ouput like `<acc_type>   <acc_no>` without any delimiters, i want to access this file based on positions in a c program

Comment: When asking such questions, please always include an example of your desired output so we can understand what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
printf  "%-2s%18s%s\n" $acc_type " " $acc_no >> out.csv
```

format string is

- %2s : two char wide column, left aligned
- %18s : 18 char wide, will be blank
- %s a string.